# GoLang SDK for Google cloud SQL

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Is the GoLang client library for Google Cloud SQL fully functional? How to get started? I can only find listing database instances example:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/admin-api/libraries

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/go/getting-started/using-cloud-sql

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the complete api](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/sqladmin/v1beta4)-- it's beta but fairly complete

```
type AclEntry
func (s *AclEntry) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type ApiWarning
func (s *ApiWarning) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type BackupConfiguration
func (s *BackupConfiguration) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type BackupRun
func (s *BackupRun) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type BackupRunsDeleteCall
func (c *BackupRunsDeleteCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *BackupRunsDeleteCall
func (c *BackupRunsDeleteCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *BackupRunsDeleteCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *BackupRunsDeleteCall
func (c *BackupRunsDeleteCall) Header() http.Header
type BackupRunsGetCall
func (c *BackupRunsGetCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *BackupRunsGetCall
func (c *BackupRunsGetCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*BackupRun, error)
func (c *BackupRunsGetCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *BackupRunsGetCall
func (c *BackupRunsGetCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *BackupRunsGetCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *BackupRunsGetCall
type BackupRunsInsertCall
func (c *BackupRunsInsertCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *BackupRunsInsertCall
func (c *BackupRunsInsertCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *BackupRunsInsertCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *BackupRunsInsertCall
func (c *BackupRunsInsertCall) Header() http.Header
type BackupRunsListCall
func (c *BackupRunsListCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *BackupRunsListCall
func (c *BackupRunsListCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*BackupRunsListResponse, error)
func (c *BackupRunsListCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *BackupRunsListCall
func (c *BackupRunsListCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *BackupRunsListCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *BackupRunsListCall
func (c *BackupRunsListCall) MaxResults(maxResults int64) *BackupRunsListCall
func (c *BackupRunsListCall) PageToken(pageToken string) *BackupRunsListCall
func (c *BackupRunsListCall) Pages(ctx context.Context, f func(*BackupRunsListResponse) error) error
type BackupRunsListResponse
func (s *BackupRunsListResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type BackupRunsService
func NewBackupRunsService(s *Service) *BackupRunsService
func (r *BackupRunsService) Delete(project string, instance string, id int64) *BackupRunsDeleteCall
func (r *BackupRunsService) Get(project string, instance string, id int64) *BackupRunsGetCall
func (r *BackupRunsService) Insert(project string, instance string, backuprun *BackupRun) *BackupRunsInsertCall
func (r *BackupRunsService) List(project string, instance string) *BackupRunsListCall
type BinLogCoordinates
func (s *BinLogCoordinates) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type CloneContext
func (s *CloneContext) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type Database
func (s *Database) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type DatabaseFlags
func (s *DatabaseFlags) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type DatabaseInstance
func (s *DatabaseInstance) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type DatabaseInstanceFailoverReplica
func (s *DatabaseInstanceFailoverReplica) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type DatabasesDeleteCall
func (c *DatabasesDeleteCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *DatabasesDeleteCall
func (c *DatabasesDeleteCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *DatabasesDeleteCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *DatabasesDeleteCall
func (c *DatabasesDeleteCall) Header() http.Header
type DatabasesGetCall
func (c *DatabasesGetCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *DatabasesGetCall
func (c *DatabasesGetCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Database, error)
func (c *DatabasesGetCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *DatabasesGetCall
func (c *DatabasesGetCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *DatabasesGetCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *DatabasesGetCall
type DatabasesInsertCall
func (c *DatabasesInsertCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *DatabasesInsertCall
func (c *DatabasesInsertCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *DatabasesInsertCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *DatabasesInsertCall
func (c *DatabasesInsertCall) Header() http.Header
type DatabasesListCall
func (c *DatabasesListCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *DatabasesListCall
func (c *DatabasesListCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*DatabasesListResponse, error)
func (c *DatabasesListCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *DatabasesListCall
func (c *DatabasesListCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *DatabasesListCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *DatabasesListCall
type DatabasesListResponse
func (s *DatabasesListResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type DatabasesPatchCall
func (c *DatabasesPatchCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *DatabasesPatchCall
func (c *DatabasesPatchCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *DatabasesPatchCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *DatabasesPatchCall
func (c *DatabasesPatchCall) Header() http.Header
type DatabasesService
func NewDatabasesService(s *Service) *DatabasesService
func (r *DatabasesService) Delete(project string, instance string, database string) *DatabasesDeleteCall
func (r *DatabasesService) Get(project string, instance string, database string) *DatabasesGetCall
func (r *DatabasesService) Insert(project string, instance string, database *Database) *DatabasesInsertCall
func (r *DatabasesService) List(project string, instance string) *DatabasesListCall
func (r *DatabasesService) Patch(project string, instance string, database string, database2 *Database) *DatabasesPatchCall
func (r *DatabasesService) Update(project string, instance string, database string, database2 *Database) *DatabasesUpdateCall
type DatabasesUpdateCall
func (c *DatabasesUpdateCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *DatabasesUpdateCall
func (c *DatabasesUpdateCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *DatabasesUpdateCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *DatabasesUpdateCall
func (c *DatabasesUpdateCall) Header() http.Header
type DemoteMasterConfiguration
func (s *DemoteMasterConfiguration) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type DemoteMasterContext
func (s *DemoteMasterContext) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type DemoteMasterMySqlReplicaConfiguration
func (s *DemoteMasterMySqlReplicaConfiguration) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type ExportContext
func (s *ExportContext) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type ExportContextCsvExportOptions
func (s *ExportContextCsvExportOptions) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type ExportContextSqlExportOptions
func (s *ExportContextSqlExportOptions) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type ExportContextSqlExportOptionsMysqlExportOptions
func (s *ExportContextSqlExportOptionsMysqlExportOptions) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type FailoverContext
func (s *FailoverContext) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type Flag
func (s *Flag) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type FlagsListCall
func (c *FlagsListCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *FlagsListCall
func (c *FlagsListCall) DatabaseVersion(databaseVersion string) *FlagsListCall
func (c *FlagsListCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*FlagsListResponse, error)
func (c *FlagsListCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *FlagsListCall
func (c *FlagsListCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *FlagsListCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *FlagsListCall
type FlagsListResponse
func (s *FlagsListResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type FlagsService
func NewFlagsService(s *Service) *FlagsService
func (r *FlagsService) List() *FlagsListCall
type ImportContext
func (s *ImportContext) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type ImportContextCsvImportOptions
func (s *ImportContextCsvImportOptions) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesAddServerCaCall
func (c *InstancesAddServerCaCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesAddServerCaCall
func (c *InstancesAddServerCaCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesAddServerCaCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesAddServerCaCall
func (c *InstancesAddServerCaCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesCloneCall
func (c *InstancesCloneCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesCloneCall
func (c *InstancesCloneCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesCloneCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesCloneCall
func (c *InstancesCloneCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesCloneRequest
func (s *InstancesCloneRequest) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesDeleteCall
func (c *InstancesDeleteCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesDeleteCall
func (c *InstancesDeleteCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesDeleteCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesDeleteCall
func (c *InstancesDeleteCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesDemoteMasterCall
func (c *InstancesDemoteMasterCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesDemoteMasterCall
func (c *InstancesDemoteMasterCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesDemoteMasterCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesDemoteMasterCall
func (c *InstancesDemoteMasterCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesDemoteMasterRequest
func (s *InstancesDemoteMasterRequest) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesExportCall
func (c *InstancesExportCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesExportCall
func (c *InstancesExportCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesExportCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesExportCall
func (c *InstancesExportCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesExportRequest
func (s *InstancesExportRequest) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesFailoverCall
func (c *InstancesFailoverCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesFailoverCall
func (c *InstancesFailoverCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesFailoverCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesFailoverCall
func (c *InstancesFailoverCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesFailoverRequest
func (s *InstancesFailoverRequest) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesGetCall
func (c *InstancesGetCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesGetCall
func (c *InstancesGetCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*DatabaseInstance, error)
func (c *InstancesGetCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesGetCall
func (c *InstancesGetCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *InstancesGetCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *InstancesGetCall
type InstancesImportCall
func (c *InstancesImportCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesImportCall
func (c *InstancesImportCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesImportCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesImportCall
func (c *InstancesImportCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesImportRequest
func (s *InstancesImportRequest) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesInsertCall
func (c *InstancesInsertCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesInsertCall
func (c *InstancesInsertCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesInsertCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesInsertCall
func (c *InstancesInsertCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesListCall
func (c *InstancesListCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesListCall
func (c *InstancesListCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*InstancesListResponse, error)
func (c *InstancesListCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesListCall
func (c *InstancesListCall) Filter(filter string) *InstancesListCall
func (c *InstancesListCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *InstancesListCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *InstancesListCall
func (c *InstancesListCall) MaxResults(maxResults int64) *InstancesListCall
func (c *InstancesListCall) PageToken(pageToken string) *InstancesListCall
func (c *InstancesListCall) Pages(ctx context.Context, f func(*InstancesListResponse) error) error
type InstancesListResponse
func (s *InstancesListResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesListServerCasCall
func (c *InstancesListServerCasCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesListServerCasCall
func (c *InstancesListServerCasCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*InstancesListServerCasResponse, error)
func (c *InstancesListServerCasCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesListServerCasCall
func (c *InstancesListServerCasCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *InstancesListServerCasCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *InstancesListServerCasCall
type InstancesListServerCasResponse
func (s *InstancesListServerCasResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesPatchCall
func (c *InstancesPatchCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesPatchCall
func (c *InstancesPatchCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesPatchCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesPatchCall
func (c *InstancesPatchCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesPromoteReplicaCall
func (c *InstancesPromoteReplicaCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesPromoteReplicaCall
func (c *InstancesPromoteReplicaCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesPromoteReplicaCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesPromoteReplicaCall
func (c *InstancesPromoteReplicaCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesResetSslConfigCall
func (c *InstancesResetSslConfigCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesResetSslConfigCall
func (c *InstancesResetSslConfigCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesResetSslConfigCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesResetSslConfigCall
func (c *InstancesResetSslConfigCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesRestartCall
func (c *InstancesRestartCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesRestartCall
func (c *InstancesRestartCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesRestartCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesRestartCall
func (c *InstancesRestartCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesRestoreBackupCall
func (c *InstancesRestoreBackupCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesRestoreBackupCall
func (c *InstancesRestoreBackupCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesRestoreBackupCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesRestoreBackupCall
func (c *InstancesRestoreBackupCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesRestoreBackupRequest
func (s *InstancesRestoreBackupRequest) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesRotateServerCaCall
func (c *InstancesRotateServerCaCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesRotateServerCaCall
func (c *InstancesRotateServerCaCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesRotateServerCaCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesRotateServerCaCall
func (c *InstancesRotateServerCaCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesRotateServerCaRequest
func (s *InstancesRotateServerCaRequest) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesService
func NewInstancesService(s *Service) *InstancesService
func (r *InstancesService) AddServerCa(project string, instance string) *InstancesAddServerCaCall
func (r *InstancesService) Clone(project string, instance string, instancesclonerequest *InstancesCloneRequest) *InstancesCloneCall
func (r *InstancesService) Delete(project string, instance string) *InstancesDeleteCall
func (r *InstancesService) DemoteMaster(project string, instance string, instancesdemotemasterrequest *InstancesDemoteMasterRequest) *InstancesDemoteMasterCall
func (r *InstancesService) Export(project string, instance string, instancesexportrequest *InstancesExportRequest) *InstancesExportCall
func (r *InstancesService) Failover(project string, instance string, instancesfailoverrequest *InstancesFailoverRequest) *InstancesFailoverCall
func (r *InstancesService) Get(project string, instance string) *InstancesGetCall
func (r *InstancesService) Import(project string, instance string, instancesimportrequest *InstancesImportRequest) *InstancesImportCall
func (r *InstancesService) Insert(project string, databaseinstance *DatabaseInstance) *InstancesInsertCall
func (r *InstancesService) List(project string) *InstancesListCall
func (r *InstancesService) ListServerCas(project string, instance string) *InstancesListServerCasCall
func (r *InstancesService) Patch(project string, instance string, databaseinstance *DatabaseInstance) *InstancesPatchCall
func (r *InstancesService) PromoteReplica(project string, instance string) *InstancesPromoteReplicaCall
func (r *InstancesService) ResetSslConfig(project string, instance string) *InstancesResetSslConfigCall
func (r *InstancesService) Restart(project string, instance string) *InstancesRestartCall
func (r *InstancesService) RestoreBackup(project string, instance string, instancesrestorebackuprequest *InstancesRestoreBackupRequest) *InstancesRestoreBackupCall
func (r *InstancesService) RotateServerCa(project string, instance string, instancesrotateservercarequest *InstancesRotateServerCaRequest) *InstancesRotateServerCaCall
func (r *InstancesService) StartReplica(project string, instance string) *InstancesStartReplicaCall
func (r *InstancesService) StopReplica(project string, instance string) *InstancesStopReplicaCall
func (r *InstancesService) TruncateLog(project string, instance string, instancestruncatelogrequest *InstancesTruncateLogRequest) *InstancesTruncateLogCall
func (r *InstancesService) Update(project string, instance string, databaseinstance *DatabaseInstance) *InstancesUpdateCall
type InstancesStartReplicaCall
func (c *InstancesStartReplicaCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesStartReplicaCall
func (c *InstancesStartReplicaCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesStartReplicaCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesStartReplicaCall
func (c *InstancesStartReplicaCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesStopReplicaCall
func (c *InstancesStopReplicaCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesStopReplicaCall
func (c *InstancesStopReplicaCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesStopReplicaCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesStopReplicaCall
func (c *InstancesStopReplicaCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesTruncateLogCall
func (c *InstancesTruncateLogCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesTruncateLogCall
func (c *InstancesTruncateLogCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesTruncateLogCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesTruncateLogCall
func (c *InstancesTruncateLogCall) Header() http.Header
type InstancesTruncateLogRequest
func (s *InstancesTruncateLogRequest) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type InstancesUpdateCall
func (c *InstancesUpdateCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *InstancesUpdateCall
func (c *InstancesUpdateCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *InstancesUpdateCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *InstancesUpdateCall
func (c *InstancesUpdateCall) Header() http.Header
type IpConfiguration
func (s *IpConfiguration) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type IpMapping
func (s *IpMapping) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type LocationPreference
func (s *LocationPreference) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type MaintenanceWindow
func (s *MaintenanceWindow) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type MySqlReplicaConfiguration
func (s *MySqlReplicaConfiguration) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type OnPremisesConfiguration
func (s *OnPremisesConfiguration) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type Operation
func (s *Operation) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type OperationError
func (s *OperationError) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type OperationErrors
func (s *OperationErrors) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type OperationsGetCall
func (c *OperationsGetCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *OperationsGetCall
func (c *OperationsGetCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *OperationsGetCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *OperationsGetCall
func (c *OperationsGetCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *OperationsGetCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *OperationsGetCall
type OperationsListCall
func (c *OperationsListCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *OperationsListCall
func (c *OperationsListCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*OperationsListResponse, error)
func (c *OperationsListCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *OperationsListCall
func (c *OperationsListCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *OperationsListCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *OperationsListCall
func (c *OperationsListCall) MaxResults(maxResults int64) *OperationsListCall
func (c *OperationsListCall) PageToken(pageToken string) *OperationsListCall
func (c *OperationsListCall) Pages(ctx context.Context, f func(*OperationsListResponse) error) error
type OperationsListResponse
func (s *OperationsListResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type OperationsService
func NewOperationsService(s *Service) *OperationsService
func (r *OperationsService) Get(project string, operation string) *OperationsGetCall
func (r *OperationsService) List(project string, instance string) *OperationsListCall
type ReplicaConfiguration
func (s *ReplicaConfiguration) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type RestoreBackupContext
func (s *RestoreBackupContext) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type RotateServerCaContext
func (s *RotateServerCaContext) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type Service
func New(client *http.Client) (*Service, error)
type Settings
func (s *Settings) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type SslCert
func (s *SslCert) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type SslCertDetail
func (s *SslCertDetail) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type SslCertsCreateEphemeralCall
func (c *SslCertsCreateEphemeralCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *SslCertsCreateEphemeralCall
func (c *SslCertsCreateEphemeralCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*SslCert, error)
func (c *SslCertsCreateEphemeralCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *SslCertsCreateEphemeralCall
func (c *SslCertsCreateEphemeralCall) Header() http.Header
type SslCertsCreateEphemeralRequest
func (s *SslCertsCreateEphemeralRequest) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type SslCertsDeleteCall
func (c *SslCertsDeleteCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *SslCertsDeleteCall
func (c *SslCertsDeleteCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *SslCertsDeleteCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *SslCertsDeleteCall
func (c *SslCertsDeleteCall) Header() http.Header
type SslCertsGetCall
func (c *SslCertsGetCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *SslCertsGetCall
func (c *SslCertsGetCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*SslCert, error)
func (c *SslCertsGetCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *SslCertsGetCall
func (c *SslCertsGetCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *SslCertsGetCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *SslCertsGetCall
type SslCertsInsertCall
func (c *SslCertsInsertCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *SslCertsInsertCall
func (c *SslCertsInsertCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*SslCertsInsertResponse, error)
func (c *SslCertsInsertCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *SslCertsInsertCall
func (c *SslCertsInsertCall) Header() http.Header
type SslCertsInsertRequest
func (s *SslCertsInsertRequest) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type SslCertsInsertResponse
func (s *SslCertsInsertResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type SslCertsListCall
func (c *SslCertsListCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *SslCertsListCall
func (c *SslCertsListCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*SslCertsListResponse, error)
func (c *SslCertsListCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *SslCertsListCall
func (c *SslCertsListCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *SslCertsListCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *SslCertsListCall
type SslCertsListResponse
func (s *SslCertsListResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type SslCertsService
func NewSslCertsService(s *Service) *SslCertsService
func (r *SslCertsService) CreateEphemeral(project string, instance string, sslcertscreateephemeralrequest *SslCertsCreateEphemeralRequest) *SslCertsCreateEphemeralCall
func (r *SslCertsService) Delete(project string, instance string, sha1Fingerprint string) *SslCertsDeleteCall
func (r *SslCertsService) Get(project string, instance string, sha1Fingerprint string) *SslCertsGetCall
func (r *SslCertsService) Insert(project string, instance string, sslcertsinsertrequest *SslCertsInsertRequest) *SslCertsInsertCall
func (r *SslCertsService) List(project string, instance string) *SslCertsListCall
type Tier
func (s *Tier) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type TiersListCall
func (c *TiersListCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *TiersListCall
func (c *TiersListCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*TiersListResponse, error)
func (c *TiersListCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *TiersListCall
func (c *TiersListCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *TiersListCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *TiersListCall
type TiersListResponse
func (s *TiersListResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type TiersService
func NewTiersService(s *Service) *TiersService
func (r *TiersService) List(project string) *TiersListCall
type TruncateLogContext
func (s *TruncateLogContext) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type User
func (s *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type UsersDeleteCall
func (c *UsersDeleteCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *UsersDeleteCall
func (c *UsersDeleteCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *UsersDeleteCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *UsersDeleteCall
func (c *UsersDeleteCall) Header() http.Header
type UsersInsertCall
func (c *UsersInsertCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *UsersInsertCall
func (c *UsersInsertCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *UsersInsertCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *UsersInsertCall
func (c *UsersInsertCall) Header() http.Header
type UsersListCall
func (c *UsersListCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *UsersListCall
func (c *UsersListCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*UsersListResponse, error)
func (c *UsersListCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *UsersListCall
func (c *UsersListCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *UsersListCall) IfNoneMatch(entityTag string) *UsersListCall
type UsersListResponse
func (s *UsersListResponse) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error)
type UsersService
func NewUsersService(s *Service) *UsersService
func (r *UsersService) Delete(project string, instance string, host string, name string) *UsersDeleteCall
func (r *UsersService) Insert(project string, instance string, user *User) *UsersInsertCall
func (r *UsersService) List(project string, instance string) *UsersListCall
func (r *UsersService) Update(project string, instance string, name string, user *User) *UsersUpdateCall
type UsersUpdateCall
func (c *UsersUpdateCall) Context(ctx context.Context) *UsersUpdateCall
func (c *UsersUpdateCall) Do(opts ...googleapi.CallOption) (*Operation, error)
func (c *UsersUpdateCall) Fields(s ...googleapi.Field) *UsersUpdateCall
func (c *UsersUpdateCall) Header() http.Header
func (c *UsersUpdateCall) Host(host string) *UsersUpdateCall
```